# How to update text file when loading ajax request? Eclipse tomcat

Tags: jquery, ajax, eclipse, tomcat

So i'm loading a text file on a html page like this:

```
$("#container").load("http://localhost:8080/Ajax/chatsave/test.txt");
```

The text file loads correctly however on the same page i also have a small form where the user enters some input and that input gets appended to the text file. So it gets appended to the text file but it doesn't get updated on the html page, so thats what the problem is. Below is my code for the form and servlet:

```
 //form input gets sent to servlet
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method:"post",
            data:{message: $("#message").val()},
            url: "getTextServlet",
            success: function(data, status){
                alert(status)
            }
        });
```

Servlets appends submited input to textfile:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String param = request.getParameter("message");
    
    if(param != null) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\proje\\eclipse-workspace\\Ajax\\WebContent\\chatsave\\test.txt");
        
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        if(file.createNewFile()) {
            //creates file if it doesn't excist
            
        } else {
            
            //here we append the submited input to our text file
            writer.write("[CLIENT]: " + param);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: You're modifying the file in your workspace rather than where it's deployed for Tomcat. Is your workspace set to refresh and build automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "You're modifying the file in your workspace rather than where it's deployed for Tomcat.". And yes both refresh and build are automatic.

Comment: Are you seeing the alert you wrote execute?

Comment: Yes i do see it.

Comment: The text gets appended immediately to the text file but it doesn't load only after like 2/3 mins on the html page and also after i reload the page.

Comment: That makes sense, load() doesn't do that for you, it's a one-time operation

Comment: So if load() doesn't do that, then what does?

Comment: Executing the same load() statement as the callback on success, I'd think. It's not a "watch."

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, does it?